# get paperclip attach url from custom find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

i have two models, User has_many Message.

User model has an avatar attachment with paperclip. I have a complex find that returns users data and i need to return the avatar url too.

I can't do something like user.avatar.url because the find does not return a User object.

Is there any way to work around this and get the attach url?

running rails 2.3.8

Comment: please write you find method. do you write belongs_to :user in Message model?

Comment: i think it doesnt matter, what is important is if exists maybe a paperclip class method so i can pass the object id, class and retrieve attach's url